# Start an activity from the thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class which generates a pdf file. 
This class is extended by Activity that means is have onCreate, onPause (and so on) methods.

While a pdf file is generating it takes some time to be generated so I need to show a progress bar to notify the user that the file is generating at the moment.

Everything works fine expect that when I click on a generate button the progress bar freezes for a few seconds (according to Logcat: progress bar freezing while file is generating).

So my problem is that, that I don't know how to make the progress bar unstoppable while the file is generating.

Below is my code:

```
Log.i(TAG, "PDF generation: " + position);

final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setMessage("Generating...");
dialog.show();

new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            PdfGenerator.class));

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.hide();
            }
        });

    }

}).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as for starting an Activity from Thread using runOnUiThread:

```
///... your code here..

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Your_Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                dialog.cancel();

                // START ACTIVITY HERE
               Your_Current_Activity.this.startActivity(new 
                        Intent(Your_Current_Activity.this,
                                       PdfGenerator.class));

                }
            });

        }

    }).start();
```

Comment: Now it looks like good but I did some changes. I have changed dialog.hide() to dialog.cancel() and moved after starting a new activity.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @juliuks : but `runOnUiThread `is method of Activity class then without using Activity context it's not possible to access it.most welcome firend :)

Comment: I think you didn't understand me what changes I did.
Btw, the code now looks like: http://pastebin.com/fxB1Zz9i

Comment: @juliuks : yes you are doing right remember one point `Stats.this` is important when you want to access `runOnUiThread`