# Starting a new activity after info is received in other thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

here's a part of my code: after button is clicked, new thread and connection to server are started. If connection is sucessfull, app should start new activity and end current. Can someone explain which way is best for to do that?

```
    transThread.submit(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    guiProgressDialog(true);
                    if(user.length() < 4) guiNotifyUser("Username must have at least 4 characters!");
                    else if(pass.length() < 4) guiNotifyUser("Password must have at least 4 characters!");
                    else if(!pass.equals(passrtp)) guiNotifyUser("Password is not same in both fields!");
                    else if(!isValidEmail(mail)) guiNotifyUser("Your email is not valid email address!");
                    else if(fname.equals("") || lname.equals("")) guiNotifyUser("All fields are mandatory!");
                    else {
                        try {
                            final String message = AutoDiaryHttpHelper.signUp(user, md5(pass), mail, fname, lname);
                            guiNotifyUser(message);
//if message equals something start new activity

                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    guiProgressDialog(false);
                }
            });

            break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) for that. [Here is a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779742/start-an-activity-from-the-thread) that shows how to do that.

I personally like to use `AsyncTask` for this. You can do your work in `doInBackground()` then return a value to `onPostExecute()` and start the `Activity` from there or do whatever you need on the `UI`.

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean))

[Here is an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455858/using-asynctask-to-speed-up-android-app-launch-time/15456047#15456047) that shows the basic structure and important details of using `AsyncTask`

**Edit from code in comment**

I can't say the exact error you are getting without logcat but the first problem I see is when you initialize `context` in `AsyncTask`. You don't want to use `getApplicationContext()` especially not the way you are. I imagine you are getting a `NPE` because `context` is not yet initialized. You are passing `Context` in the constructor so you would just do

```
this.context = context
```

However, it looks like your `AsyncTask` is an inner class of `RegisterActivity` which means it has access to all member variables of `RegisterActivity` and its `Context`. This means that to start your `Activity` you can use `RegisterActivity.this` instead of `context`.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {                     
          super.onPostExecute(result);                       
          //if (result == "Successful registration!")                    
          //String i;
          //i = "da";
          context.startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));  // change this here
```

As stated, your constructor isn't needed for `context` if its an inner class but if it was a separate file it would be like

```
class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            Context context;
            private RegisterTask(Context context){
                    this.context = context;  // use the variable (context) passed in the constructor above
```

Comment: one silly question.. if I'm already extending Activity class, how am I supposed to extend AsyncTask also?

Comment: You don't need to `extend AsyncTask`...you can simply make it an inner class of your `Activity`

Comment: ok, here's how i tried to do it, but i'm making mistakes somehow(i'll post whole class, so i will do it on pastebin - please just focus on AsyncTask part ):
http://pastebin.com/1ETPC1Un
From what i saw, app chrashes on line where i call new activity
If you could point errors in code for me(or better explain them), that would be great.

Comment: Is your `AsyncTask` an inner class of your `RegisterActivity` or a separate file?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic see my edit. Specifically the `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: thanks again, I've managed to understand it and to make it works. I've posted whole solution in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that solved my problem (thanks to CodeMagic - I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this):
Inner class:

```
class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String message = null;
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.register_username_text );
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.register_password_text );
        EditText passwordrtp = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.register_repeatpassword_text );
        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.register_email_text );
        EditText firstname = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.register_firstname_text );
        EditText lastname = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.register_lastname_text );
        final String user = username.getText().toString();
        final String pass = password.getText().toString();
        final String passrtp = passwordrtp.getText().toString();
        final String mail = email.getText().toString();
        final String fname = firstname.getText().toString();
        final String lname = lastname.getText().toString();

        guiProgressDialog(true);
        if(user.length() < 4) guiNotifyUser("Username must have at least 4 characters!");
        else if(pass.length() < 4) guiNotifyUser("Password must have at least 4 characters!");
        else if(!pass.equals(passrtp)) guiNotifyUser("Password is not same in both fields!");
        else if(!isValidEmail(mail)) guiNotifyUser("Your email is not valid email address!");
        else if(fname.equals("") || lname.equals("")) guiNotifyUser("All fields are mandatory!");
        else {
            try {
                message = AutoDiaryHttpHelper.signUp(user, md5(pass), mail, fname, lname);
                guiNotifyUser(message);//prosla vodi na sledeci activity "Succesfull registration"

            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        guiProgressDialog(false);



        return message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Successful registration!"))
        {

            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class));
            RegisterActivity.this.finish();
        }


    }
}
```

and call from button listener:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.register_register_button:

        RegisterTask registerTask = new RegisterTask();
        registerTask.execute();

        break;
```